# Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in C:\wamp\www\form

Tags: php

I started building a multi-lingual web, and get an error when entering the following code

```
echo"<div class=header-konten><?php echo $lang['".$kategori_nama."'];?> </div>";
```

Comment: echo inside an echo?!?

Comment: ...well, echo does make the same sound repetitively, just not in this case ;-)

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to Mark Baker's answer, the error is probably on another line before this one. You need to show more context to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo"<div class='header-konten'>" . $lang[$kategori_nama] . "</div>";
```

Comment: While this is the correct syntax, I don't see how it will fix the error the OP got. There's nothing in what he posted that would cause a PHP parse error, since `<?php` is inside a string. The problem is probably on the line before what he posted, he may be missing a semicolon or closing quote.

Comment: Taking just this portion: `<?php echo $lang['".$kategori_nama."'];?>`, you have `echo $lang['"` so far so good, but then you try to concatenate `$kategori_nama` onto a non-string. Mark's fix is right.